# Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) installing and running Sql instant client via sqlplus command

Tags: 14.04, oracle

I have installed oracle instant client on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) using following instructions [Oracle instant client 11.2.0.4.0](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client). 
It's works fine with sqlPlus64 command and I can able to connect to my DB.
My problem is I need to run command **sqlplus** ,  (we have some ant script with is configured with sqlplus command).

I tried installing 'Instant Client for Linux x86' , but it was throwing some compatibility issue.

Anyway to run command sqlplus not sqlplus64?

Comment: It should probably enough to create a symlink named `sqlpplus` pointing on `sqlplus64`

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/sqlplus64 /usr/bin/sqlplus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to create a symlink named `sqlplus` pointing at `sqlplus64`
Just execute the following in a Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/sqlplus64 /usr/bin/sqlplus
```